# Combining OpenCV's Viz3d and imshow yields segmentation fault

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, 3d

I try to show a Viz3d window and a regular window with OpenCV (3.2 or 3.3, compiled with QT 5 on Ubuntu 16.04), at the same time. When I do this, I get a segmentation fault when my program exits, i.e., when I press a key in the regular (imshow) window. This is a minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/viz.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::viz;

int main()
{
  Viz3d visualization("Test");
  visualization.showWidget("Test object", WCone(1, 0.5, 100));
  visualization.setWindowPosition(Point2i(0, 0));
  visualization.spinOnce(1, true);

  cv::imshow("Test window", Mat(100, 100, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0)));
  moveWindow("Test window", 800, 0);

  while (!visualization.wasStopped())
  {
    if (waitKeyEx(1) != -1)
      break;
    visualization.spinOnce(1, true);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Using only imshow or only a Viz3d window works perfectly fine. Are there any special options that one needs to set when using both types of windows? I could not find anything relevant about this in the documentation.

This is the call stack I see in gdb:

```
Thread 1 "test" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x0) at ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:67
67  ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x0) at ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:67
#1  0x00007fffee79be27 in XrmDestroyDatabase () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
#2  0x00007fffee50b3bb in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6
#3  0x00007fffee50c04a in XtCloseDisplay () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6
#4  0x00007fffee50c0c1 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6
#5  0x00007fffee50c25c in XtDestroyApplicationContext () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6
#6  0x00007ffff54a06cd in vtkXRenderWindowInteractor::~vtkXRenderWindowInteractor() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkRenderingOpenGL-6.2.so.6.2
#7  0x00007ffff54a06f9 in vtkXRenderWindowInteractor::~vtkXRenderWindowInteractor() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkRenderingOpenGL-6.2.so.6.2
#8  0x00007ffff2111409 in vtkObjectBase::UnRegisterInternal(vtkObjectBase*, int) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkCommonCore-6.2.so.6.2
#9  0x00007ffff21133a5 in vtkObject::UnRegisterInternal(vtkObjectBase*, int) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkCommonCore-6.2.so.6.2
#10 0x00007ffff47004be in vtkRenderWindowInteractor::UnRegister(vtkObjectBase*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkRenderingCore-6.2.so.6.2
#11 0x00007ffff46f81ba in vtkRenderWindow::UnRegister(vtkObjectBase*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkRenderingCore-6.2.so.6.2
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#12 0x00007ffff7b8e310 in cv::viz::Viz3d::VizImpl::~VizImpl() () from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_viz.so.3.2
#13 0x00007ffff7b8e3f9 in cv::viz::Viz3d::VizImpl::~VizImpl() () from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_viz.so.3.2
#14 0x00007ffff7b846ae in cv::viz::Viz3d::release() () from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_viz.so.3.2
#15 0x00007ffff7bbff0d in cv::viz::VizStorage::removeUnreferenced() () from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_viz.so.3.2
#16 0x00007ffff7b846c5 in cv::viz::Viz3d::release() () from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_viz.so.3.2
#17 0x0000000000402e0f in main () at test.cpp:11
```

Comment: Your example compiles and runs fine on my setup: Ubuntu 12.04, OpenCV 3.2 that I compiled myself (without QT I think).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I tried both, OpenCV 3.2 and 3.3. I did not try it without QT yet.